# How can I make a popup with dynamic elements? Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup

I am trying to make a popup similar to the one on snapchat having dynamic elements inside the view. I will have to display the data randomly and change it depending on the options provided in the UI. 
The "Add" button will be changed with either "Added"/"Blocked" (and I should be able to change the status with a button from another popup)
What would be the recommended way to do this?
I attached a [provided mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJsY8.png)

Comment: I would just use a UIViewController presented modally in modal presentation style form sheet

Comment: Should I do the same with the second popup that is going to be displayed over the first one?

Comment: take a look at `https://github.com/kevin0571/STPopup`. its a framework that does pretty much what your looking for. look at the code and see how it works to get an idea of how its done

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController I love this library as it manages lot of things automatically. We just need to set dynamic content.